WebLogic request takes too long to respond
I am maintaining a backend in Spring Boot. All requests work in a normal time, except for one process that takes too long. I tested with the Spring Boot server and a WebLogic Local server on my PC and the request in both takes maximum 40 seconds, but when doing the same from production WebLogic it takes up to 330 seconds.
This is the controller:
@GetMapping("/mismatched-redes/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getMismatchedRedes(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        MemoryMXBean memoryBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
        MemoryUsage beforeMemoryUsage = memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
        long beforeUsedMemory = beforeMemoryUsage.getUsed();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        rgisHojaRedesRepository.deleteLogsByIdHojaRedes(id);
        boolean hasErrors =  datosRedesComparison.compareData(id);

        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        if (hasErrors) {
            response.put("hasErrors", true);
            response.put("mensaje", "Se encontraron errores en las redes.");
        } else {
            response.put("hasErrors", false);
            response.put("mensaje", "No se encontraron errores en las redes.");
        }

        rgisHojaRedesRepository.updateHojaEstado(id, hasErrors ? "CON ERRORES" : "SIN ERRORES", "REDES");

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;

        MemoryUsage afterMemoryUsage = memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
        long afterUsedMemory = afterMemoryUsage.getUsed();
        long memoryUsed = afterUsedMemory - beforeUsedMemory;

        response.put("duracion", duration / 1000 + " segundos");
        response.put("memoriaUsada", memoryUsed / 1024 / 1024 + " MB");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Connect-TimeOut", String.valueOf(minutosEspera))
                .header("Read-TimeOut", String.valueOf(minutosEspera))
                .body(response);
    }

And this function is the one that makes the request take longer:
public boolean compareData(Long id) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        boolean hasErrors;
        metodosRedesService.reloadData(id);
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> comparePosteTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> comparePoste(id));
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> compareEstructuraMTTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> compareEstructuraMT(id));
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> compareEstructurasBTTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> compareEstructuraBT(id));
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> compareLuminariasTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> compareLuminarias(id));
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> compareTensoresTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> compareTensores(id));
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> compareTrafoTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> compareTrafo(id));
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> compareSeccionadoresTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> compareSeccionadores(id));
        CompletableFuture<Boolean> compareDuplicatedTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> compareDuplicated(id));
        
        
        CompletableFuture.allOf(compareEstructuraMTTask, compareEstructurasBTTask,comparePosteTask,
        compareLuminariasTask, compareTensoresTask, compareTrafoTask, compareDuplicatedTask,
        compareSeccionadoresTask).join();
        
        hasErrors =  compareEstructuraMTTask.getNow(false) || comparePosteTask.getNow(false) ||
        compareEstructurasBTTask.getNow(false) || compareLuminariasTask.getNow(false) ||
        compareTrafoTask.getNow(false) || compareTensoresTask.getNow(false) ||
        compareDuplicatedTask.getNow(false) || compareSeccionadoresTask.getNow(false);
        
        return hasErrors;
    }

I thought it would be out of memory error because in my local WebLogic several times it stopped because I had max 512MB of memory for JVM and the proccess maximun requires 1GB, but I increased it to 2GB and it worked correctly, and in the production WebLogic it also increased to 2GB but it still runs in too much time compared to the local one.
I have spent a lot of time searching but can't find something similar, if anyone had the same problem happen please could you help me, thanks.

maybe it is a memory leak, take a heapdump to analyze the memory
